# FOUC on foundation topbar dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, css, web, zurb-foundation, frontend

I'm trying to style a topbar menu with submenu items in Foundation. The code seems right, but the submenu items keep breaking the styling of the topbar on a page refresh, then going into place (hidden under the top menu item) when the javascript loads.

The [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/dropdown-menu.html#preventing-fouc) address FOUC on the dropdown arrows, but not on the list items themselves.

Code:

```
<div class="top-bar">
<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
  <li class="is-dropdown-submenu-parent">
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1E</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1F</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1G</a></li>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRowMw

This flashing also happens on the official codepen: https://codepen.io/IamManchanda/pen/XRYWPO